# How to Modify Taxonomy.php to Show All Posts for Custom Post Type and Custom Taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, archive, taxonomy, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm building a Wordpress site, and I'm trying to figure out how to modify `taxonomy.php` to display all of the posts in a custom category and custom taxonomy, but I'm stuck. Here's the situation:

I have a custom post type called 'work.' Within that custom post type, I have a custom taxonomy called 'project type' where I have created several categories called photography, video, print design, etc. I set up a template called `taxonomy.php` which governs mydomain.com/work as well as mydomain.com/project-type/print-design/. The problem is that these pages only display the 5 most recent posts. I need them to display all the posts in the proper category (or in the case of mydomain.com/work, all of the posts in the custom post type regardless of category).

I found [this page about query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) which helped me realize that I needed to add `<?php query_posts( array ( 'post_type' => 'work', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>`. Now the work page is loading correctly, but all of the category pages are loading all the work posts (because I've defined the post_type as work in that snippet I added).

**How can I generalize the code so that it makes the work page display all of the work posts and the category pages display only the relevant category posts?** Here's the code in full:

```
<?php

/**
 * Project Type Taxonomy Archive
 */

$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
?>

<h3 style="color:#EEEEEE"><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?> PROJECTS</h3>

<ul class="thumbnails">
    <div id="work">

    <?php if ( !empty( $term->description ) ): ?>
        <div class="archive-description">
        <?php echo esc_html($term->description); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php query_posts( array ( 'post_type' => 'work', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post">
        <li class="span4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="tint"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featured-thumb' ); ?></div></a>
            <br />
            <div class="thumbcaption">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3><?php the_title() ?></h3></a>
                <p> <?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <p><i><?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'work_project_type' ,  ' ' ); ?></i></p>
            </div>  
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="navigation clearfix">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('« Previous Entries') ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Next Entries »') ?></div>
    </div>

    <?php else: ?>

    <h2 class="post-title">No Projects in <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?></h2>
    <div class="content clearfix">
        <div class="entry">
            <p>It seems there aren't any projects in <strong><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?></strong> right now. Check back later, I try to add new projects regularly.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Someone told me to look into WP_Query, but I cannot figure out how to use it for what I need to do...

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with this would be to not add a custom template.

When your go to a url relating to a taxonomy archive wordpress has already got all the posts out of the database. By creating a separate template although you have easier control over the query args like 'posts_per_page' it would be nicer to not have to do your own query.

Instead consider doing a pre_get_posts filter. Something like this.

```
// if on a certain taxonomy archive page, do not limit the posts
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query){
    if (isset($query->query_vars['name_of_your_taxonomy'])) {
        add_filter('post_limits', function($limit){
            /*
            default will be something like this 'LIMIT 0, 10'
            but we don't want a limit so return empty string
            */
            return '';
        });
    }
});
```